Harmonic function is constant
I cannot solve this question from the mid-term exam last year.
Question. Suppose that $u:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic. And for all $z\in\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$, $$u(z)\leq 2|\log |z||+1.$$ Prove that $u$ is constant.
My Approach. Typically, when aiming to establish the constancy of holomorphic functions, invoking Liouville's Theorem proves fruitful. We can morph a harmonic function into a holomorphic one by defining $f=u+iv$, where
v represents a conjugate function. For example, if $u$ remains non-positive across $\mathbb {C}$, this approach proves effective, such as this. However, the challenge here lies in the non-constancy of the right-hand side. Directly employing the given condition merely yields $|e^{u+iv}|\leq e|z|^2$. Evidently, $e|z|^2$ lacks boundedness.
Perhaps leveraging the fact that $\log |z|$ is harmonic might yield insight.

Denote by $f(z)$ the entire function we get from $u$.
If $|z|\geq1$, then $|e^{f(z)}|\leq e^{2|\log|z||+1}=e^{2\log|z|+1}=e|z|^2$. This implies that $e^{f}$ is a polynomial (of degree less than or equal to $2$).
By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, if $e^f$ were not constant, it would have a root. But we always have $|e^f|>0$, so $e^f$ is constant.
This in turn implies $e^{|u(z)|}=|e^f|$ and $|u(z)|$ are constant. As $u$ is continuous (being harmonic), we must have that $u$ is constant.

Thanks! Now I fully understand the proof of this question.
